# crontab output file by attachment

Tags: cron, email, output

I cannot receive the crontab output report by email as an attachment.
I tried the following code, but I receive a blank file:

```
50 * * * * root touch /home/text_created >> 
/home/log_crontab.txt | mail -s "Email Subject" -a "/home/log_contab.txt" 
this_is_my_email
```

It is a really simple test just to run crontab along with its email sending feature.
What's the matter with the code above?

Comment: You can't split a `crontab` command over multiple lines like that.

Answer (score 2):

You received a blank file because the `/home/log_contab.txt` file was empty when the mail  was sent.

**Why:**

Processes on the both sides of the anonymous pipe (`|`) start simultaneously; so, when the command on the left hand side appends STDOUT (assuming any) to the `/home/log_contab.txt` file, the `mail` command has finished executing (with a blank `/home/log_contab.txt` file as attachment as presumably it was empty to start with).

To get what you want, run one after another, *conditionally*:

```
50 * * * * command_1 && command_2
```

Change the commands accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Piping the output to `mail` is not right. You're redirecting the output to a file, so nothing will be sent to the pipe. And when you use a pipe, the two commands are run concurrently, so `mail` doesn't wait for the first command to finish.

Run them sequentially with `;`.

And `touch` doesn't produce any output. If you want a message logging that the cron job succeeded, you need to write that explicitly.

```
50 * * * * root if touch /home/text_created; then echo "Touch successful"; else echo "Touch failed"; fi >> /home/log_crontab.txt 2>&1; mail -s "Email Subject" -a "/home/log_contab.txt" this_is_my_email
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is not working. I just tried this code: ``*/2 0 * * *  root touch /home/file_created_at_`date +\%H:\%M`.txt > /home/log.txt ; mail -s "subject" -a "/home/log.txt" my_email``. It outputs again a blank file.

Comment: @R99Photography AFAIK the `touch` command doesn't write anything to standard output - what exactly are you expecting to see in the attached file?

Comment: `touch` is only an example of a task I expect to run. Let's imagine another task like "copy a directory from one location to another one for backyp", I expect to send an email with the log that the crojob was succesfully run.

Comment: Copying a file doesn't produce any output, either.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you can log a message reporting the success of the operation.

Comment: The cron job in the question runs `touche`. I didn't know that was just a typo for `touch`, I assumed it was a real command that produces output.

Comment: What if the log is created at 17:00 (for instance), when the script starts and the script ends many minutes after?

Comment: @R99Photography Why should that make any difference? It will send the mail when it's done.